# firebase user authentication . add data after user login

Tags: firebase-authentication

I want to save data after user login

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
  console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}
```

How can add data after login .

```
ref.child('users').child('info').set({ "name": "john", "age": 770 });
```

Please help me.

Comment: See section 5 "Authenticate Your Users" on this page: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to save data about the user:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var authData = ref.getAuth();
if (authData) {
  ref.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('info').set({ "name": "john", "age": 770 });
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}
```

Note that this is covered pretty well in the [Firebase documentation section on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing). That also shows a better way of doing this: by listening to the `onAuth()` event.